# blocked by CORS policy in REACT

Tags: reactjs, cors

I recently created a react create app and tried to connect it with the Backend but when making requests it is giving CORS problems.

Problem 1:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7022/Leads/106/status' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

Problem 2:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7022/Leads/1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

How can I solve these problems?

I researched some solutions but they all talked about the server and react doesn't have that control.

Comment: *"but they all talked about the server"* - Which is exactly where you'd solve that problem.  The server needs to allow cross-origin requests.

Comment: "they all talked about the server" They are correct to do so. You have *some kind of server* at localhost:7022; that's where you need to fix things.

Answer (score -1):

go to chrome web store extension

Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

add it

on it then run it

install it (add it )
[image]
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en-US&utm_source=ext_sidebar

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried and in the problem 1 continues to present the problem

Comment: This would only solve the issue for people who install the extension. That's... not going to be useful for a website intended for the public.